# Не могу импортировать модули через pip

Tags: python, telegram-bot

[image: Вот ошибка]Пишу telegram бота на python. Установил модуль командой:
`pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. Вроде установилось без проблем, но когда я попытался импортировать модуль командой `import telebot`. У меня вывело ошибку. Что делать?

Comment: Расскажете, какую ошибку? Или рассчитываете на хрустальные шары и телепатию местных знатоков? :)

Comment: Код - это текст. А текст должен быть текстом, а не фотографией. Это первое. Второе - ты уже пытался самостоятельно решить проблему. Только на этом сайте примерно 102030 вопросов и ответов с такой проблемой. Ты потрудился ознакомиться хотя бы с одним?

Comment: Кстати, через pip модули не импортируют.

Comment: а самое главное, как же вы "пишите телеграм бота", если вы даже по сути до кода не добрались? это звучит так как "я лечу на Марс, только я пока что даже понятия не имею как строят и запускают ракеты"

Comment: какой редактор кода используешь, ставил ли ты вирутальную среду?

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего в другую директорию установился, ну или же вы создали проект в другой директории